# Object not found in apache

Tags: linux, apache, manjaro

I'm using Archlinux and i installed mariadb, apache, php, php-apache, and phpmyadmin. if i request to **/myUrl/api/** I got:

```
{
  "ok": false,
  "code": null,
  "message": null,
  "result": [
    
  ]
}
```

This result. But when i try with some exist methods for example **/myUrl/api/login** i got

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.56 (Unix) PHP/8.2.4
```

error.
Here my .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried to enable **mod_rewrite** and I uncommented **#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so** in **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**  and restarted httpd however result not changed. I'm new so please give detailed answer. Thanks